# How to get FIRST response in a join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working with this query:

```
select t1.*, t2.Value from `db.ds.table1` t1
join `db.ds.table2` t2
on t1.Address= t2.Address
```

t2.Value is identical in all join matches on Address.  however, the query cartesians.

how do set the join, so I get just the "first" response from the join, and not ALL of them?

btw, there's close to 300mil per table.

Thanks!

Comment: yup.  thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> t2.Value is identical in all join matches on Address ...

*... so it really not necessarily the first but rather any ...*

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT t1.*, t2.value 
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1
JOIN (
  SELECT address, ANY_VALUE(value) value 
  FROM `project.dataset.table2` 
  GROUP BY address
) t2
ON t1.address = t2.address
```

Comment: Wouldn't SELECT DISTINCT be faster than GROUP BY with ANY? Never tried that combination.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t1.*, t2.Value
from `db.ds.table1` t1 join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by address order by ?) as seqnum
      from `db.ds.table2` t2
     ) t2
     on t2.address = t1.address and t2.seqnum = 1;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering -- what "first" means.

Comment: This has a great chance of blowing up while sorting (in the `partition` function) on BQ end..

Comment: @khan . . . I would not call that a "great chance", unless you can read something into the question that I don't see.  I don't see why a field called `address` would be so skewed.  Please share reasons why you think it is necessarily skewed.

Comment: He mentioned he is dealing with 300m rows in each of the tables.. plus in your answer, `row_number()` is generated over by ordering an unknown field which could possibly be a blob of text, so, just saying ... may not be best of the ideas.